# How to add extra option to cfselect other than default?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a drop down where I show the options of a query and the default
is from a specific column.

I want to add a extra option 'None' to the list. How would I do this?

```
<th>Image</th>
<td>
  <cfselect name="image" query="UnionQuery2" value="name" display="name">
    <option>#tesing11#</option>
  </cfselect>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation of cfselect](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_r-s_14.html), use the queryPosition attribute.  The docs even have an example showing exactly what you want to do.